# Create an *.xlsb in linux

Tags: excel, linux, xlsb

Does anyone know how to create or export data to an xlsb file (Binary File Format) in a Linux OS from any programming language?

My idea is to execute it from R, but any suggestion in Python, Perl or some other language is very appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the JavaScript library [SheetJS](https://github.com/sheetjs/js-xlsx). 
It supports export to Excel 2007+ binary Format.
[image]

Comment: Thank you very much, your solution is very good and I will consider it for other projects, but in this case it does not allow me to work with large files.

Comment: ~30 Mb, 15 columns and 140.000 rows, but I am trying with 50.000 rows and it does not work either. However, with small files it works very well.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like there's a way to do it using C++. You might look at [the EasyXLS library](https://www.easyxls.com/manual/tutorials/cpp/export-data-to-xlsb-file.html), there's a free trial but it appears to be $295 for a license, so if it's a personal project it might not be ideal. If it's a project for work, though, you might try it out, because it seems that the library is very easy to use (go figure from the name, I guess), and you can set rows, columns, and even different tabs in the Excel sheet. The link above shows an example of how to use it, I hope this helps.

**Edit:** C++ appears to be the only language that has a library for this that is compatible with Linux. I found [this one here](https://docs.aspose.com/display/cellscpp/Read+and+Write+XLSB+file+format) that only works with Windows, and [this method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31654526/need-to-save-xls-workbook-as-xlsb-with-vba) only works with VBA, which you could use by running it with Wine, but the first method seems to be the only one that can run natively on Linux without issue.

Comment: You can use EasyXLS with Java and Python. It does not work with C++ in Linux.

Comment: Thank you very much, EasyXLS + Java look nice but I need to find a free solution.

Answer (score 2):

You may want to look at this: 
[How to create Excel (.XLS and .XLSX) file in C# without installing Ms Office?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/151005/how-to-create-excel-xls-and-xlsx-file-in-c-sharp-without-installing-ms-offic)
You could just use the library through Mono and, depending on what you are doing, you could write some kind of shell utility or possibly link your program to Mono and make some type of wrappers.  It really seems that, for this particular application, something in .NET is probably where you will find the most complete solution, and then it should work through Mono on linux.