# How to save an excel file from xlsx to xlsb to make file smaller using vba and ms-access?

Tags: excel, vba, ms-access, xlsb

I currently am ingesting excel files through a button on ms-access. The issue I am facing is that the excel files are rather large (~20MB). I noticed that if I change the file format to xlsb the files are significantly smaller (~2MB). However, I am not sure how this might affect my data validations because I need to iterate through each row of the excel files, and also multiple sheets. So not 100% if this is a viable method to make the file size smaller.

How I am currently creating excel objects though vba code linked to Access button:

```
public sub init(sheetName As String, filePath As Variant)
    Set objExcel = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
    Set objFile = objExcel.Workbooks.Open(filePath)
    Set objSheet = objFile.Worksheets(sheetname)
    Set sheet = objSheet

End Sub
```

Is there a way to revise the init method so that I dont have to open the file itself (because this is a time consuming process). If I can instead convert the file on the fly and then only use the xlsb object that is what would make this much faster.

Currently it takes 30 seconds to open a 20MB file using the above method. Whereas when I open the same file but converted to xlsb it takes a second.

When I researched this a lot of suggestions were to use: ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs FileName:= ActiveWorkbook.Path

Is this the most effective way? I need the quickest process possible, and I dont want to open the excel file because of time. I have hundreds of excel files that I need to import and validate.

Other resources I looked into:

[Need to save xls workbook As xlsb with VBA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31654526/need-to-save-xls-workbook-as-xlsb-with-vba)

https://www.mrexcel.com/board/threads/convert-xlsx-workbook-to-xlsb-using-macro.1133145/

[Batch convert .xls to .xlsx with VBA without opening the workbooks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29167539/batch-convert-xls-to-xlsx-with-vba-without-opening-the-workbooks)

Comment: You have to open the file in Excel in order to convert it. There is no other option. .xlsx files are basically zip files - you can open them in WinZIP or any other zip utility and access the contents. .xlsb is a binary format instead, which is why it's smaller. Excel is the only thing that can  do the conversion, and it's done through the SaveAs functionality.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first link you posted has relevant code.

This can be done with Excel automation in Access VBA, consider:

```
Public Sub OpenWorkbook()
    Dim xlApp As Excel.Application, wbWorkbook As Excel.Workbook
    Set xlApp = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
    Set wbWorkbook = xlApp.Workbooks.Open("filepath\filename.xlsx")
    wbWorkbook.SaveAs "filepath\filename.xlsb", 50
    xlApp.Quit
End Sub
```

If that's too slow because of file size, there is no solution.

Comment: Thanks. So there is no way to not open the file first? Id like to have them all converted to xlsb at once if possible.

Comment: Already stated opening in some manner is required.